# How to change object's property in getter function of dependent variable in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, class, oop, properties, getter

Let's say we have a class which has "prop" as property and "depProp" is "Dependent" property. Moreover, it will have getter function to calculate "depProp". The class definition would be like :

```
classdef Program
    properties 
        prop = 200;  
        
    end
    properties (Dependent)
        depProp
    end
    methods 
        function val = get.depProp(obj)
            val = prop*rand;
            if val>100
                obj.prop = 100; % gives an error 
            end
        end
    end
end
```

However, MATLAB gives an error because get.depProp function does not return "obj" as output so it cannot change the property of object. I know why it is happenning (it is value class and the object must be returned). I do not want to switch to handle class. So how can I change the object's property in the getter function of dependent variable. Inefficient solutions are also welcome.
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of the property you need a setter function, see [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/access-methods-for-dependent-properties.html).

```matlab
classdef Program
    properties 
        prop = 200;  
        
    end
    properties (Dependent)
        depProp
    end
    methods 
        function val = get.depProp(obj)
            val = obj.prop * rand;
        end

        function obj = set.depProp(obj, val)
            if val > 100
                obj.prop = 100;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But it looks like what you are trying to do is to change the object *while getting its value*. I think that the only way to do such a thing is to use a handle class. Without a handle class, the only way to change the object is by returning the object from your function. You need a syntax such as `[obj, val] = obj.depProp`.

Using a handle class, it could look like this. Note that you don't need a dependent property, a regular function suffices:

```matlab
classdef Program < handle
    properties 
        prop = 200;  
    end
    methods 
        function val = depProp(obj)
            val = obj.prop * rand;
            if val > 100
                obj.prop = 100;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now you can do:

```matlab
obj = Program;
obj.depProp
obj.depProp
```